# Select ul with odd li's

Tags: jquery, html, list, html-lists

For a dynamic website I'm trying to create a list of items, where the last `li` (if odd) is 100% wide.

I got this working, the problem I have is that the next `UL`, also does it, while the last `li` isn't odd.

Basically: If the last `LI` in the list is odd, then make 100%.

I'm having an hard time trying to explain myself, so hopefully my fiddle makes more sense:

```
var target = $( "ul.odd-list > li:last-child");
if ( target.is(":nth-child(odd)"  ) ) { 
    target.css( "width", "98%");
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/freekfc/Ln5uf9y1/4/)

Thanks in advance!

ps, I know that i can remove the class from the second `ul`. But that one has to be there in case the decide to add more `li`'s.

Comment: Why are you doing this in jQuery and not pure css?

Comment: I dont want every :last-child to be 100%. Only the ones that are odd. If the item is even, nothing had to be done. jQuery was my most logical option. If you can tell me how to do it with css, please let me know!

Comment: So you are saying: `ul.odd-list > li:nth-child(odd):last-child {
 width: 98%;
}`
 would not work? http://jsfiddle.net/z5q2572t/1/ Edit: I see the accepted answer is the same thing. ;)

Comment: wasn't saying that, cause i never tried it :) But it does work, so thanks.

Comment: @FreekvanderHorst Well be glad you asked, now you learned something new! :)

Comment: Yes, for this project I will use the CSS solution, I will keep the jQuery somewhere safe tho, you never know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your default width looks like to be 48% width. Lets keep it like it and apply 98% width where needed.

in css :

```
li {
   width : 48%;
 }
li:last-child:nth-child(odd) {
   width: 98%;
}
```

if you really want to use jquery to set last width :

```
$('ul.odd-list > li:last-child:nth-child(odd)').css('width', '98%')
```

note : TrueBlueAussie answer is right too but I don't like using 'if' where there is no need of it.

Comment: I had no clue you could add a :last-child and :nth to one element. So thanks for this.

Comment: Re reference. I don't like the `if` either, hence the second version :)

Comment: @FreekvanderHorst this is particularly useful when using :hover ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to test each one separately as `is` will return true if any one of the matching elements meets the condition:

JSFIddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/Ln5uf9y1/5/

```
var target = $("ul.odd-list > li:last-child");
target.each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":nth-child(odd)")) {
        $(this).css("width", "98%");
    }
});
```

Which you can reduce to a single selector:

```
$("ul.odd-list > li:last-child:nth-child(odd)").css("width", "98%");
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/Ln5uf9y1/7/